# 12.04 won't run Gnome desktop

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic

I've been running with Ubuntu Unity for a while but I installed Gnome for my son to use, it worked when I first set it up but now it doesn't matter what option I pick at the login screen it boots to Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried purging and reinstalling.  Maybe something got botched up.

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Comment: I have now - still the same

Comment: Try logging in with a new user account http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-createdisable-and-delete-new-user-account-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot.html

Comment: Please note that you can make your autoremovals purges too with `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`.